# Getting ratings from aria-label with beautiful soup

Tags: web-scraping, beautifulsoup, text-mining

I have a soup object like:

```
r = requests.get('https://www.yelp.com/biz/panera-bread-markham')
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
```

and I'm trying to find the ratings from the following code,

```
rating_list = soup.find_all('span', {"class":"lemon--span__373c0__3997G display--inline__373c0__1DbOG border-color--default__373c0__2oFDT"})
rating_list
```

the output is a list like this,

```
[<span class="lemon--span__373c0__3997G display--inline__373c0__1DbOG border-color--default__373c0__2oFDT"><div aria-label="3 star rating" class="lemon--div__373c0__1mboc i-stars__373c0__Y2F3O i-stars--large-3__373c0__2oM4P border-color--default__373c0__2oFDT overflow--hidden__373c0__8Jq2I" role="img"><img alt="" class="lemon--img__373c0__3GQUb offscreen__373c0__1KofL" height="560" src="https://s3-media0.fl.yelpcdn.com/assets/public/stars.yelp_design_web.yji-9bec2045845c24d3bff3ddb582884eda.png" width="132"/></div></span>,
 <span class="lemon--span__373c0__3997G display--inline__373c0__1DbOG border-color--default__373c0__2oFDT"><div aria-label="4 star rating" class="lemon--div__373c0__1mboc i-stars__373c0__Y2F3O i-stars--regular-4__373c0__3acau border-color--default__373c0__2oFDT overflow--hidden__373c0__8Jq2I" role="img"><img alt="" class="lemon--img__373c0__3GQUb offscreen__373c0__1KofL" height="560" src="https://s3-media0.fl.yelpcdn.com/assets/public/stars.yelp_design_web.yji-9bec2045845c24d3bff3ddb582884eda.png" width="132"/></div></span>,
 <span class="lemon--span__373c0__3997G display--inline__373c0__1DbOG border-color--default__373c0__2oFDT"><div aria-label="5 star rating" class="lemon--div__373c0__1mboc i-stars__373c0__Y2F3O i-stars--regular-5__373c0__ySHIl border-color--default__373c0__2oFDT overflow--hidden__373c0__8Jq2I" role="img"><img alt="" class="lemon--img__373c0__3GQUb offscreen__373c0__1KofL" height="560" src="https://s3-media0.fl.yelpcdn.com/assets/public/stars.yelp_design_web.yji-9bec2045845c24d3bff3ddb582884eda.png" width="132"/></div></span>,
 <span class="lemon--span__373c0__3997G display--inline__373c0__1DbOG border-color--default__373c0__2oFDT"><div aria-label="3 star rating" class="lemon--div__373c0__1mboc i-stars__373c0__Y2F3O i-stars--regular-3__373c0__1DXMK border-color--default__373c0__2oFDT overflow--hidden__373c0__8Jq2I" role="img"><img alt="" class="lemon--img__373c0__3GQUb offscreen__373c0__1KofL" height="560" src="https://s3-media0.fl.yelpcdn.com/assets/public/stars.yelp_design_web.yji-9bec2045845c24d3bff3ddb582884eda.png" width="132"/></div></span>,
 <span class="lemon--span__373c0__3997G display--inline__373c0__1DbOG border-color--default__373c0__2oFDT"><p class="lemon--p__373c0__3Qnnj text__373c0__2pB8f text-color--mid__373c0__3G312 text-align--left__373c0__2pnx_ text-size--small__373c0__3SGMi"><span aria-hidden="true" class="lemon--span__373c0__3997G icon__373c0__ehCWV icon--18-check-in" style="width:18px;height:18px;fill:#0077bc"><svg class="icon_svg" height="18" viewbox="0 0 18 18" width="18" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path d="M18 9l-2.136-1.84.932-2.66-2.772-.525-.524-2.77-2.66.93L8.997 0 7.163 2.136 4.5 1.206l-.525 2.77-2.77.524.932 2.66L0 9l2.137 1.84-.932 2.66 2.77.525.526 2.77 2.664-.932L8.998 18l1.84-2.137 2.662.932.524-2.77 2.772-.524-.932-2.66L18 9zm-9.85 3.23L5.324 9.4l1.13-1.13 1.698 1.696 3.396-3.395 1.13 1.134-4.525 4.525z"></path></svg></span> <!-- -->1 check-in</p></span>,
 <span class="lemon--span__373c0__3997G display--inline__373c0__1DbOG border-color--default__373c0__2oFDT"><div aria-label="1 star rating" class="lemon--div__373c0__1mboc i-stars__373c0__Y2F3O i-stars--regular-1__373c0__14nrQ border-color--default__373c0__2oFDT overflow--hidden__373c0__8Jq2I" role="img"><img alt="" class="lemon--img__373c0__3GQUb offscreen__373c0__1KofL" height="560" src="https://s3-media0.fl.yelpcdn.com/assets/public/stars.yelp_design_web.yji-9bec2045845c24d3bff3ddb582884eda.png" width="132"/></div></span>,
 <span class="lemon--span__373c0__3997G display--inline__373c0__1DbOG border-color--default__373c0__2oFDT"><p class="lemon--p__373c0__3Qnnj text__373c0__2pB8f text-color--mid__373c0__3G312 text-align--left__373c0__2pnx_ text-size--small__373c0__3SGMi"><span aria-hidden="true" class="lemon--span__373c0__3997G icon__373c0__ehCWV icon--18-check-in" style="width:18px;height:18px;fill:#0077bc"><svg class="icon_svg" height="18" viewbox="0 0 18 18" width="18" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path d="M18 9l-2.136-1.84.932-2.66-2.772-.525-.524-2.77-2.66.93L8.997 0 7.163 2.136 4.5 1.206l-.525 2.77-2.77.524.932 2.66L0 9l2.137 1.84-.932 2.66 2.77.525.526 2.77 2.664-.932L8.998 18l1.84-2.137 2.662.932.524-2.77 2.772-.524-.932-2.66L18 9zm-9.85 3.23L5.324 9.4l1.13-1.13 1.698 1.696 3.396-3.395 1.13 1.134-4.525 4.525z"></path></svg></span> <!-- -->1 check-in</p></span>,
         <span class="lemon--span__373c0__3997G display--inline__373c0__1DbOG border-color--default__373c0__2oFDT"><div aria-label="1 star .....
    .
    .
    .
```

Any suggestion on getting the ratings from `<div aria-label="3 star rating"` ?

Answer (score 2):

There's a lot ways actually, by loading the `JSON` from `script` tag, or find the assigned div. but i think the following way is clear enough :)

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


def main(url):
    r = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')
    target = soup.findAll("meta", itemprop="author")
    for tar in target:
        print(tar['content'], tar.findNext("meta")['content'])


main("https://www.yelp.com/biz/panera-bread-markham")
```

Output:

```
Shia L. 4.0
Ryan L. 5.0
Chi K. 3.0
Joan T. 1.0
Nicky D S. 4.0
Matthew K. 3.0
Michelle W. 1.0
Jennifer C. 4.0
Niral P. 3.0
Shajitha R. 1.0
Veronica C. 3.0
Tanveer K. 1.0
Joey J. 2.0
Broadwaygirl M. 1.0
Sheena Y. 3.0
Wendy B. 4.0
Jacqueline L. 2.0
Mi S. 3.0
Sharon M. 2.0
Eduni C. 1.0
```

Comment: this worded perfect, thanks! do you know how to do it with div though?